# How to display float values in textfield in iphone?

Tags: iphone, floating-point, uitextfield

Im new to iphone, i have one textfield, when i click custom number button the value will print in the textfield, I Want to enter the value in a textField, If i enter a value the value should come to the left side of the decimal point, how?

Example: 12345

I want this
123.45

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear - are you trying to set the text in a `UITextField`? Have you tried:

```
[myTextField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", myFloat]];
```

Where `myFloat` is your floating-point variable. The `%.2f` statement inside the string will print `myFloat` to 2 decimal places.

Hope this is what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowing the user to enter text into a text field and you want to insert a decimal point then you should catch the `UIControlEventEditingChanged` event on the textfield and use it to reprocess the text. e.g.

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(reprocessTextFieldText:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

...


-(void)reprocessTextFieldText:(UITextField *)sender
{
    // enforce rules on sender.text here.
}
```

If you explicitly want to take away the user's ability to type anything other than digits then you might also want to add a delegate to your `UITextField` and implement `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
 enteredtext = @"0";
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
if([string isEqualToString:@"0.00"])
    enteredtext = @"0";
if(range.length==1)
{
    if(enteredtext.length>1)
        enteredtext = [[enteredtext substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,enteredtext.length-1)]retain];
}
else
{
    if(enteredtext.length<9)
        enteredtext = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",enteredtext,string]retain];;
}
double amountindecimal = [enteredtext floatValue];
double res=amountindecimal * pow(10, -2);
NSString * neededstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",res];
if([neededstring isEqualToString:@"0.00"])
    enteredtext = @"0";;
textField.text = neededstring;
return NO;
}
```