# How to display float values like $0.00 in textfield in iphone?

Tags: iphone

Im new to iphone, i have one textfield, when i click custom number button the value will print in the textfield, If i enter a value in textfield Example(1234), but i want float value like 0.00. how?

Example

text1.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%d", text1.text, num.tag];

1234

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display float values in textfield in iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052671/how-to-display-float-values-in-textfield-in-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

text1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%0.2f", 1234];

Here you can replace 1234 with the variable you want

Answer (score 0):

You should see NSNumberFormater.

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter=[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
[text1 setText:[numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[text1.text floatValue]]];
```